# How do I encode/decode an enum in Swift 2.0 with Xcode 7

Tags: swift, enums, xcode7

With Swift 1.2 under Xcode 6.1, you could use

```
aCoder.encodeObject(self.myEnumVariable.rawValue, forKey:"myEnumVariable")
```

but this is not valid in Swift 2.0 under Xcode 7

```
(error: MyEnum has no member 'rawValue')
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please add the `MyEnum` definition.

Comment: Nothing changed between Swift 1.2 and Swift 2 in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

You must define your enum with an underlying type for this to work.

```
enum MyEnum: Int {
//         ^^^^^
   case Cool, Awesome;
}
```